# If $f$ is continuous and bounded, there exists $x_n\to\infty$, with $\,f(T+x_n)-f(x_n)\to 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f$ be continuous and bounded in $(x_0, \infty)$.

> Prove that for every $T>0$, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$, such that $x_n\to\infty\,$ and $f\,(T+x_n)-f(x_n)\to 0$, as $n\to\infty$

**Attempt**
I tried to reason by contradiction and consider $x_{n+1}=x_n+T$. Want to prove that if we choose the starting point appropriately, such $x_n$ will converge to a limit. You do not need to continue my line of reasoning though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence 
$$
a_n=f(nT).
$$
If $$b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}\to 0,$$ we are done. Also, if $\{b_n\}$ contains a subsequence tending to zero, we are also done.

Assume that there is no subsequence of $\{b_n\}$ tending to zero. This implies that there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ and an $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
|b_n|\ge \varepsilon, \quad \text{for all $n\ge n_0$.}
$$
Clearly, this implies that there exist infinite $n$'s for which $b_n\ge \varepsilon$ and infinite $n$'s for which $b_n\le -\varepsilon$. Otherwise, we would have that $a_n\to \infty$ or $a_n\to -\infty$.

Therefore, there exist infinitely many $n$'s, such that
$$
a_n-a_{n-1}=b_n\ge \varepsilon\quad\text{and}\quad
a_{n+1}-a_n =b_{n+1}\le -\varepsilon.
$$
or equivalently
$$
f(nT)-\varepsilon\ge f\big((n-1)T),\,f\big((n+1)T)
$$
Set 
$g(x)=f(x+T)-f(x)$. Then 
$$
g\big((n-1)T\big)=f(nT)-f\big((n-1)T\big)\ge\varepsilon\qquad\text{while}\qquad
g(nT)=f\big((n+1)T)-f(nT)\le -\varepsilon
$$
and hence IVT implies that there exists a $x_n\in\big((n-1)T,nT\big)$, such that
$$
0=g(x_n)=f(x_n+T)-f(x_n).
$$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you write, "Otherwise, we would have that $a_n\to \infty$ or  $a_n\to -\infty$" ? Isn't $\epsilon$ fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If false, there exists $T\in \mathbb R$ such that

$$\liminf_{x\to \infty} |f(T+x)-f(x)| = \epsilon >0.$$

This implies there exists $a>0$ such that

$$|f(T+x)-f(x)| > \epsilon/2$$

for $x>a.$ Use the continuity of $f$ to see one of the following must hold for $x>a$:

$$i) \, f(T+x)-f(x) > \epsilon/2,;\,\,\,\,ii)\, f(T+x)-f(x) < -\epsilon/2 .$$

Suppose $i)$ holds and see where that leads.

Comment: This is where $x_{n+1}=x_n+T$ comes into play. Thanks for the hint!