# Show that continuous bounded function has a "periodic" sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show this: We have a bounded and continuous function $f:(a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ (where a is a real number). Then for every $T>0$ there exists a sequence $a_n$ such that $f(a_n+T)-f(a_n)\to 0$. I tried to suppose the opposite aiming for a contradiction but didn't quite get there.
Any hints?

Comment: Asked many times e.g. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809282/if-f-is-continuous-and-bounded-there-exists-x-n-to-infty-with-ftx-n?noredirect=1 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555965/prove-that-for-any-constant-we-may-obtain-x-n-fx-n-c-fx-n-to-0?noredirect=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that for any constant we may obtain $x_n$ : $f(x_n + C) - f(x_n) \to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555965/prove-that-for-any-constant-we-may-obtain-x-n-fx-n-c-fx-n-to-0)